# Тег для создания звука в javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите, тег для создания звука в javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <embed autostart="true" hidden="true" src="Wav.wav" name="someName" MASTERSOUND>
```

Решение не является кроссбраузерным...

Вообще уже было тут

Comment: спасибо, но не получается

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите это [audio.js](http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/), а тег называется [audio](http://htmlbook.ru/html/audio) и он принадлежит к html5